# nodejs variable undefined when exporting

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Hey I was wondering why the following returns undefined:

```
let variable;

module.exports.initialize = () => {
  variable = "123";
};

module.exports.variable = variable;
```

I simply require the module in file A and then call the initialize function. In file B I require it and console.log the variable but it returns undefined. What am I missing here?

Comment: Well obviously you never called `initialize()` before you exported the variable's value?

Comment: @Bergi I have in file A,  which I didn't include for simplicity purposes.

Comment: But you call that *after* the value `undefined` has been exported

Answer (score 5):

In JavaScript there are two types of values: 1) **primitive type** and 2) **reference type**. **primitive** values are always copied by their value and **reference types** are always copied by their references (not by their values).

Examples of primitive values: `undefined, null, boolean, string, number`.
Examples of reference types: every types other than primitive types. e.g., `Object, array` etc. See the snippet below.

### Example of Primitive type

```js
let a = 10;
let b = a;

console.log(a);
console.log(b);

b = 20;

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

### Example of Reference type

```js
let obj_a = {value: 1}
let obj_b = obj_a;

console.log(obj_a);
console.log(obj_b);

obj_b.value = 20;

console.log(obj_a);
console.log(obj_b);
```

So when you declare the variable as `let variable` its value is `undefined` and when you assign `module.exports.variable = variable` then you're just setting it's value to `undefined`.

See the example below.

```js
const myExports = {};

let variable;

function initialize() {
  variable = 10;
}

myExports.variable = variable;

console.log(variable);
console.log(myExports.variable);

initialize();

console.log(variable);
console.log(myExports.variable);
```

But if you were to initialize the the `variable` with a **reference type** e.g., an **object** then `module.exports.variable` would reflect any change to the properties of your `variable` variable.

Example:

```js
const myExports = {};

let object = {};

function initialize() {
  object.value = 10;
}

myExports.variable = object;

console.log(object);
console.log(myExports.variable);

initialize();

console.log(object);
console.log(myExports.variable);
```

Hope it make sense.

Answer (score 2):

`module.exports.variable` is a property on the `module.exports` object.  When you initialize your module, you assign the value of `variable` to that `module.exports.variable` property and that value is `undefined` at the time you assign it (because the `initialize()` function has not yet been called).

So, when your module is done initializing itself, `module.exports.variable` is `undefined`.

Then, sometime later someone else calls `module.exports.initialize()` and that changes the local `variable` within your module to `"123"`.  That does not affect the value of the `module.exports.variable` property at all.  It remains `undefined`.

In the future, please don't give either a property or a variable the name `variable` as it makes it very difficult to document or discuss.  A different name that doesn't conflict with the English definition of the word `variable` would simplify discussing this code.

---

What you can do instead is export an object instead of a plain value.

```
let myObj = { name: "John"};

module.exports.setName = (name) => {
  myObj.name = name;
};

module.exports.sharedObj = myObj;
```

Then, why you import it somewhere else

```
const aModule = require('./otherModule');
console.log(aModule.sharedObj);         // {name: "John"}

aModule.setName("Bob");
console.log(aModule.sharedObj);         // {name: "Bob"}
```

Because objects in Javascript are assigned by pointer, when you did `module.exports.sharedObj = myObj;` in the module initialization, it put a pointer to `myObj` into `module.exports.sharedObj` so when `myObj` changes, anyone viewing `module.exports.sharedObj` will see that change too.  This only works this way for objects in Javascript, not for other types of values (strings, numbers, etc...).

Comment: I agree, perhaps I should've called it something else. However how do I chang e the 'variable' I'm trying to export in the initialize function?

Comment: I saw your update, thanks a lot! What about: module.exports.variable = "123"; inside the initialize function, thats a lot shorter and does not need an object at all and is shorter

Comment: @sharpness - Doing `module.exports.variable = "123"` can work, but you will have to be careful about how you import it.  If you do this: `let myVar  = require('./otherModule').variable`;, then myVar will never change.  If you import it as  `const myModule = require('./otherModule')`  and then examine `myModule.variable`, then it will work.  The key is that you have to be saving the containing object and referencing the property off that containing object.

Answer (score -2):

try initializing the variable in the module.exports.initailize function

```
module.exports.initialize = () => {
    let variable;
    variable = "123";
};



module.exports.variable = variable;
```

Comment: Now that will even throw an exception in strict mode, not just export `undefined`.